# 2 people play card match game

Tags: probability

2 people have the same 3 cards. Each have a blue, red and yellow card (shuffled). They draw out these cards simultaneously. What is the probability that they have at least 1 match. The match is judged after each draw.

ADDED: What if number of people playing is 3? How about N people?

Answer (score 2):

Your question reduces to the following: If we pick a random permutation of $3$ objects, what is the probability that no object is fixed?  Since the group $S_3$ has only $6$ elements, it is not to difficult to compute this directly.  The elements $(123)$ and $(132)$ are the only two permutations that have no fixed point.  Such permutations are called derangements.

In this case of this problem, we see that the probability of no matches is $2/6=1/3$, so at least one match occurs with probability $2/3$.

With $n$ cards, we use the following formula for the number of derangements in $S_n$:

$$n!\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$$

Noting that $S_n$ has $n!$ elements, we see that the probability of at least one match is:

$$1-\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{i-1}}{i!}$$

The first few values of this sequence are $1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3},\frac{5}{8},\frac{19}{30},\ldots$.  The limit of this sequence is $1-e^{-1}$.

Comment: What if we change the players from 2 to another number N?

Comment: @QRIUS2KNW: With $N$ players, you are asking for the number of $N$-tuples of permutations $(\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_N)$ such that each $\sigma_i$ is a derangement, and $\sigma_i(k)\ne\sigma_j(k)$ for all $k=1,\ldots,n$ and all $i\ne j$.  This seems like a fairly difficult problem, although it makes sense that someone should have studied it.  I don't have any references though.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can regard this problem as a problem on the number of permutations with fixed points on three elements via retro-actively numbering the colors such that the order in which player 1 drew is 1,2,3 than the order of player two is some permutation of $\{1,2,3\}$.

There are six permutations of this set in total, four of these six have at least one fix-point. Thus, the probability of at least one match is $4/6= 2/3$.

Answer (score 0):

We can assume without loss of generality that the first player's cards are in the order blue, red, yellow (BRY).

There are $3!=6$ possible orders of the other player's cards. These are all *equally likely*. We count the situations in which there is at least one match. One can do it by making a list. There is a match under the circumstances BYR, YRB, RBY and BRY. Thus the required probability is $\frac{4}{6}$.

**Another way:** We introduce a useful technique called the Principle of Inclusion/Exclusion (PIE).

There are $2$ ways we can have a match on the first card, if the cards are in order BRY or BYR. Similarly, there are $2$ ways we can have a match on the second card, and $2$ ways we can have a match on the third card. If we calculate $2+2+2$ we have counted $3$ times the situations in which we have a match on all three cards. But we should only count it once. So the correct count is $2+2+2-2$.